# Creating a new array element copies to the array index below it

Tags: java, arrays

When I create a new array element, it gets stored into the array index, then the array index increments to the next.

However, I am getting a different result. The array element copies down to all previous array indexes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class VectorOfContacts implements ProjTwo
{
    private int size;
    private int capacity;
    private int incrementCapacity;
    Contact[] contacts;
    File file = new File("contacts.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public VectorOfContacts()
  {
    size = 0;
    capacity = 10;
    incrementCapacity = capacity;
    contacts = new Contact[capacity];       
  }

  public int getSize()
  {
    return size;
  }

  public int getCapacity()
  {
    return capacity;
  }

  public void setSize()
  { 
    this.size = size;
  }

  public void setCapacity()
  {
    this.capacity = capacity;
  }


  //public VectorOfContacts(int inCapacity)
  //{
    //inCapacity = 100;
    //incrementCapacity = inCapacity;
  //}

  public void readInitialFromFile() 
  {
    Contact c = new Contact();
    String temp = null;
    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
        {
            temp = input.nextLine();
            String[] part = input.nextLine().split(":");
            System.out.println(part);
            String name = part[0];
            long number = Long.parseLong(part[1]);
            String comment = part[2];
            c.setName(name);
            c.setPhoneNumber(number);
            c.setComment(comment);
            contacts[i] = c;
            contacts[size] = contacts[i];
        }
        input.close();
      }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);
      }
  }

  public void writeFinalToFile()
  {
    try{
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            output.println(contacts[i]);
        }
        output.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException a){
        System.out.println("Something is wrong.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.exit(0);


  }

  public void addContact(Contact c)
  {
    addElement(c);      
  }

  public void deleteContact(String nm)
  {
    System.out.println("Delete which name?");
    nm = input.nextLine();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        if(contacts[i].getName() == nm);
        {
            contacts[i] = contacts[i+1];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Deletion confirmed");
  }

  public void showByName(String nm)
  {
    nm = input.nextLine();
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (nm.startsWith(contacts[i].getName()))
        {
            System.out.println(contacts[i]);
        }
    }
  }

  public void showByPhoneNumber(long pN)
  {
    pN = input.nextLong();
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (contacts[i].getPhoneNumber() == pN)
        {
            System.out.println(contacts[i]);
        }
    }

  }

  public void showByComment(String c)
  {
    c = input.nextLine();
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (c.startsWith(contacts[i].getComment()))
        {
            System.out.println(contacts[i]);
        }
    }
  }

  public boolean isFull()
  {
    if (size == capacity)
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
  }


  public boolean isEmpty()
  {
    if (size == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
  }

  public void addElement(Contact item)
  {
    if (isFull() == true)
    incrementCapacity();
    contacts[size] = item;
    size++;
    System.out.println("size" + size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(contacts[i]);
    }
  }

  public void incrementCapacity()
  {
    Contact[] temp_contacts = new Contact[capacity + incrementCapacity];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        temp_contacts[i] = contacts[i];
    }
    capacity = capacity + incrementCapacity;
    contacts = temp_contacts;
  }
```

}

These are the end results

```
size1
test:1234:1

size2
no:5555:2
no:5555:2

size3
jaja:1666:test
jaja:1666:test
jaja:1666:test
```

Comment: How could this work? incrementCapacity is an int but you use it as a method (`incrementCapacity()`)?. Is there any reason not to use a list?

Comment: What exactly incrementCapacity() does.

Comment: incrementCapacity is not relevant, but what it does is that if the size of array equals the capacity, the capacity increases.

Comment: post full code of `VectorOfContacts` class

Comment: @user3062918 this is exactly what [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) does. Why don't you use ArrayList instend of reinventing it?

Comment: Seems problem in `readInitialFromFile` you use one instance of `Contact` for all indexes, you need create it inside loop. Use `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

You print one object for all indexes, you need to use next:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    System.out.println(contacts[i]);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is the same.

Comment: @user3062918 post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could improve a lof of things.

- Don't expose everything as public
- The class VectorOfContacts does a lot of things. You should split it into many classes.
- Use the Java Framework  (Array.copy(), ArrayList, ...)
- Don't do if (true) return true else return false
- Write tests

In readInitialFromFile you're creating the contact outside of the loop. So you reusing the same object of all contacts.

Those setters dont do anything, you missing an argument. But they shouldn't be public anyway so you don't need them.

```
public void setSize()
{
    this.size = size;
}

public void setCapacity()
{
    this.capacity = capacity;
}
```

isFull and isEmpty shouldn't be public and can be a lot shorter

```
private boolean isFull() {
    return size == capacity;
}

private boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}
```

Please clean up your code first.